# Why does Pixijs use different elements for PointerEvent listeners?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-bubbling, pointer-events

I'm learning the source code of [Pixijs](https://pixijs.com), and I came across the part related to PointerEvent:

```
self.document.addEventListener('pointermove', this.onPointerMove, true);
this.domElement.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.onPointerDown, true);
this.domElement.addEventListener('pointerleave', this.onPointerOverOut, true);
this.domElement.addEventListener('pointerover', this.onPointerOverOut, true);
self.addEventListener('pointerup', this.onPointerUp, true);
```

Source: [EventSystem.ts#L371-L390](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/blob/b6332a7d2c3fce3e50283bd293eac431ca38bfd6/packages/events/src/EventSystem.ts#L371-L390)

This code looks strange to me and I have some questions:

1. Why does it attach event listeners to three different elements (`self`, `self.document`, and `this.domElement`)?
2. I can understand the difference between `self` and `this.domElement`, but what is the difference between `self` and `self.document`?
3. Why does it use `self` instead of `window`? Is it for running in Web Worker?
4. Finally, what is the best practice for using PointerEvent? Which events should be attached to canvas (`this.domElement`), and which should be attached to `window`/`document`? And which one should I use between `window` and `document`?

I appreciate any help or explanation. Thanks in advance.